# Solving $\int \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ using $x = sint$, limits $t \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ - why the limitation of $t$ to that interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$$
\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx
$$

I see a solution to that problem. In the solution they define:

$$
x = \sin t
$$

And say that $t$ must hold:

$$
t \in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]
$$

But i dont understand why $t$ must be in that interval.

If $t$ not in that interval, so what?

So why the limitation of $t$?

Comment: Because on that interval, the cosine is not negative (carry out the substitution and see why that matters). Moreover, that is the interval on which the arcsine is defined

Comment: Ok arcsin is realy in that interval, about the cosine, i dont see why it matters.

Comment: How did they know that we will have arcsin? or they defined the interval in the end?

Comment: Oh wait, maybe its because that get to: $\int(0.5+0.5cos2t)$ and it should be pisitive cuz its a substitution of a int of a sqrt - hence a positive value?

Comment: When you sub $x=sint$, you will get $\sqrt{1-sin^2t}$ which is $\sqrt{cos^2t}$ and that is NOT $cost$ but $|cost|$. But the absolute value in this typical trig sub can be taken off. You figure out the pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: You can take $x=\sin(t)$ for some local inverse of sine whenever $x$ is confined to $[-1,1]$, but other steps in the derivation may break, for example $\sqrt{1-\sin(t)^2}=\cos(t)$ is only true where $\cos(t) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

That is because $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ is only real when $1 - x^2 \ge 0 \implies -1 \le x\le 1$. Now, let $x = \sin t$. Therefore, $\sin^{-1}{-1} = -\dfrac\pi2\le t\le\sin^{-1}1 = \dfrac\pi2$.

Comment: That's not totally right, this works when you pick the local inverse to be arcsine, but you can do the calculation over with a different local inverse of sine just as well.